# I have to change font style to "SinSun-ExtB". It changes with write "Consolas" or "MS Gothic", for example, but not when i type "SinSum-ExtB"

Tags: c++, fonts

Here is my part of code. I want to change font style, but every style works, except for "NSimSun" and "SimSun-ExtB".

```
void setConsoleFont(short width, short height) {
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX fontInfo = {};
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, FALSE, &fontInfo);
    fontInfo.dwFontSize = { width, height };
    fontInfo.cbSize = sizeof(fontInfo);
    wcscpy_s(fontInfo.FaceName, L"SimSun-ExtB");
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, FALSE, &fontInfo);
    
    return;
}
```

I really need this style for drawing and i dont want to set it with my hands evry time. So, does anyone know what should i do or maybe its bug or smth?

btw i use VS`19 and Win10